# Why does downgrading one dependency downgrade another unrelated dependency?

Tags: go

I'm trying to downgrade one specific dependency in a golang repo by using `go get`

```
go get github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7@v7.13.1
go: downgraded github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7 v7.17.1 => v7.13.1
go: downgraded gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1 v1.39.1 => v1.36.2
```

Strange, I didn't think either of those two packages have dependencies on each other. Trying to upgrade `dd-trace-go.v1` just reverses the situation:

```
❯ go get gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1@v1.39.1
go: upgraded github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7 v7.13.1 => v7.17.1
go: upgraded gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1 v1.36.2 => v1.39.1
```

I've tried using both:

```
go list -deps github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7
go list -deps gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1/ddtrace
```

to verify neither depends on some minimum version of the other, and they don't appear to.

What am I missing here? Why does this happen and what's the best way to tell go that I want to use both v7.13.1 of go-elasticsearch and v1.39.1 of dd-trace-go.v1?

So far the only way I've been able to accomplish this is by using a `replace` directive in my go.mod file:

```
replace github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7 => github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7 v7.13.1
```

but this seems kind of hacky, and I'm assuming there's a better way.

Comment: That version of `dd-trace-go.v1` depends on `go-elasticsearch` `v7.17.1` https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-go/blob/v1.39.1/go.mod#L22

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was using the wrong `go-list` command. Looks like I should have done `go list -m gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1` or just looked in its go.mod file